# How to connect map annotation view buttons with database to go to another view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, mkmapview

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{    
    //if it's user location, return nil
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    //try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

    //button on the right for popup for pins
    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    //zoom button on the left of popup for pins
    UIButton* leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [leftButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftButton addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(zoomToLocation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftButton;

    return pinView;
}

//for map view annotation right button
-(void)showDetails:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Annotation Click");
    //fypAppDelegate *appDelegate = (fypAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //Attraction *attraction = (Attraction *)[appDelegate.attractions objectAtIndex:sender];

    infoViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"info"];
    self.infoView = viewController;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:infoView animated:true];
}

//for map view annotation left button
-(void)zoomToLocation:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Annotation Click");
}
```

Above is the delegate for the map annotations. I am able to show the pins and show the map annotation view but I don't know how to link the button events to the next view (infoViewController). 
So as you guys can see, the right button is the one I want to use to enable user to view more information about that place while the left button, I want to allow user to zoom in into the coordinates of that pin.

The data are from the database I've created. Below is how I did it just for reference (in case you guys might need it)

```
-(void)putPins
{
    fypAppDelegate *appDelegate = (fypAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];   //get data
    [appDelegate readTopAttractions];   
    int i = 0;
    int count = appDelegate.attractions.count;
    self.mapAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:appDelegate.attractions.count];
    while (i < count) {
        Attraction *attraction = (Attraction *)[appDelegate.attractions objectAtIndex:i];
        i++;

        //Set coordinates for pin
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        location.latitude = (double)[[attraction xCoor] doubleValue];
        location.longitude = (double)[[attraction yCoor] doubleValue];
        MapPin *mapPin = [[MapPin alloc] init];
        [mapPin setCoordinate:location];
        [mapPin setName: [attraction name]];
        NSString *desc = [attraction description];
        int i = 0, position;
        while(i < 50){
            if ([desc characterAtIndex:i] == ' '){
                position = i;
                i++;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
        desc = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", [desc substringToIndex:position], @"..."];
        [mapPin setDescription: desc];
        [self.mapAnnotations addObject:mapPin];
    }

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.mapAnnotations];
}
```

please do tell me if you guys need more details.
Thank you! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `showDetails:` and `zoomToLocation:` methods, you can get a reference to the annotation whose callout button was tapped by doing the following:

```
MapPin *ann = (MapPin *)[mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];
```

In `zoomToLocation:` you can then zoom in to that annotation using:

```
[mapView setRegion:
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(ann.coordinate, 500, 500) 
        //500 meters vertical span, 500 meters horizontal span
    animated:YES];
```

In `showDetails:`, you can pass `ann` or its properties to the detail view.

By the way, instead of calling custom methods using `addTarget` in `viewForAnnotation`, you can use the map view's `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method which gives more direct access to the annotation that was tapped.  For example:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    MapPin *ann = (MapPin *)view.annotation;

    if (control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView)
    {
        NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped: control=RIGHT");
        //show detail view (or you can call your custom method here)...
    }
    else
        if (control == view.leftCalloutAccessoryView)
        {
            NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped: control=LEFT");
            //zoom in (or you can call your custom method here)...
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped: unknown control");
        }
}
```

Make sure you remove the `addTarget` calls from `viewForAnnotation` if you decide to use the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method.

Comment: hi i tried using the calloutAccessoryControlTapped. but now i have another problem. The zooming part works fine now.
well for the rightCalloutAccessoryView, I can't seem to 'push' to the next view by [self.navigationalController pushViewController:infoView animated:YES]. But I can [self.view addSubview:infoView.view], which is what I do not want.

Comment: The current view controller must be in a navigation controller for the push to work.  Or, you can use presentModalViewController instead.  Or if you're using storyboard, you'll need to do it another way.

Answer (score 0):

You want to zoom in to the particular pin? Is that right?

Therefore you can use the setRegion:animated: - method from MKMapView.

Example:

```
mapView = MKMapView   
location = CLLLocationCoordinate2D  
METERS_PER_MILE = 1609.344 (defined as a Constant)

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:region];

[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

AppleDocs
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: i mean after I click the pin, and it pops up a annotation view which have a button. and I want to use that button to zoom into the pin. how do i even define 'location'

Comment: You have location already defined in your putPins-Method. Use the same way to define the location again or check if you can reuse this property.